# How do I cast a Python object to a C variable?

Tags: python, c, casting

Pretty straight forward I would think.  I'm very confident it's one of the cases where I don't know how to ask the simple question.

Trying to cast a python object (list) to an array of unsigned chars.

```
PyObject * py_data;
unsigned char c_data[MAX_LENGTH];

// py_data is filled using the PyArg_ParseTuple(....)

// Build the outbound payload
for(i=0; i < block_length; i++)
{
    c_data[i] = HOW_TO_CAST_THIS(py_data[i]);
}
```

I have read the [tutorial written by Ned Batchelder](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/whirlext.html#h_The_Hello_World_extension) which is a great read, as well as Googled with no luck.

Any other tutorials or reference recommendations would be great.

Comment: I think [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-February/035686.html) can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get items out of a tuple, you have to use [`PyTuple_GetItem`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/tuple.html#PyTuple_GetItem) (or, if you know it's a tuple, you can use the unsafe `PyTuple_GET_ITEM`). This gives you `PyObject`s.

To get `int`s from the `PyObject`s, use `PyInt_AsLong`.

**NEVER** cast `PyObject`s to C types (other than `void *`), and **never** attempt to index a `PyObject` using indexing notation (`py_data[i]`). Both will give you very bad results. Always use Python API methods to deal with `PyObject`s.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the not indexing into the PyObject.  That seems like a 'logical' thing to do and I would not have thought twice about it.  I had just found the PyInt_AsLong moments after posting the question, but would have been burned by the GetItem